# Unable to pass formData with other parameters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass formData along with other parameters to a PHP script.

Using the $.post method, I was getting an 'Illegal Invocation' error.  So I abandoned the $.post method and went to $.ajax method.

As follows:

```
$('#uploadBtn').on('click', function()
{
  var formData = new FormData($('#uploadfile')[0]); // the form data is uploaded file
  var booking = $('#bookingNum').val();
  var partner = $('#partnerCode').val();

  var parameters =
  {
    formData:formData,
    booking:booking,
    partner:partner
  } 

  $.ajax({
    url: 'process/customer.php',
    data: parameters,  // <- this may be wrong
    async: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('fail: ' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

On the PHP side, I'm trying to get the parameters object like so:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['parameters']))
{
  echo "Hello";  

  $value = $_POST['parameters'];
  // I can get the other 2 parameters like this
  $company = htmlspecialchars(trim($value['booking']));
  $partner = htmlspecialchars(trim($value['partner']));

  // not sure how to get the uploaded file information      
}
?>
```

Basically, I am uploading a file to be saved to a directory.  But the problem is, I cannot send anything over to the PHP side.  I am getting this warning:

"jquery.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

I need to be able to send the 'parameters' object over to the PHP script, then access it for processing.

How can I achieve this using the $.ajax method?  Then how do I access the formData once on the PHP side?

Comment: The error is just telling you not to use `async: false` because it's now deprecated. Your parameters should send over fine this way. I'm not a PHP guy but I'd imagine they'd be held inside `$_POST['formData']`, or `$value['formData']`.

Comment: @TylerRoper - Now, I am not getting anything.  No warning, no errors...  The problem seems to be on the PHP side now.  What am I missing?

Comment: @TylerRoper - I tried to echo "hello" on the PHP side, but I am not getting anything.  Thoughts?

Comment: Did you echo that inside your `if` or outside?

Comment: @TylerRoper - I edited the PHP above to include the echo.

Comment: I don't think `$_POST['parameters']` exists and I'm not sure how this ever worked (per your comment: `// I can get the other 2 parameters like this`) - unless your PHP does not match your JS? Your post object has three properties: `booking`, `partner`, and `formData`. Again, I'm not a PHP specialist by any means, but I'd imagine those would be `$_POST['booking']`, `$_POST['partner']`, and `$_POST['formData]'`, respectively. Because `$_POST['parameters']` doesn't exist, you're not falling into that `if ( ... )` in your PHP, which is why the `echo` isn't doing anything either.

Comment: *"I abandoned the $.post method and went to $.ajax"* - Also, you should check out the [documentation for `$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). It's just shorthand for `$.ajax`.

Comment: @TylerRoper - Yeah, when using the $.post method, I am getting an 'illegal invocation' error.

Comment: Ah yes, that's likely because sending formData requires `contentType: false,
    processData: false` which is not part of the shorthand.

Comment: You can't serialize a `FormData` as part of another object.

Comment: @Barmar - I just figured that out.  Any thoughts on how to make this work?  Maybe renaming the file prior to upload?  I'll probably have to ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters is the object you are `POSTing`. the key value pairs will be based on it's properties. Try accessing them like `$_POST['formData']` and `$_POST['booking']`.

Also... please rework your code to remove the `async:false` ... TBH this should never have been put into jQuery and is absolutely terrible. Don't feel bad, it's the first thing every newcomer tries when they first start using ajax, myself included. You're going to cause the UI thread to hang for the duration, preventing all user interaction during the call.

**EDIT**
I didn't realize you are trying to post a file at first, so this is not a complete answer as I don't think you are accessing it correctly. But The important part of this answer is that there is no `parameters` index of `$_POST` (which is why not even your echo "hello" is coming back).

if you POST an object that looks like

```
{
  key1 : "value1",
  key2 : "value2"
}
```

they will come through to php as

```
$_POST['key1'];//"value1";
$_POST['key2'];//"value2";
```

important to note, files posted to the server are typically found in the $_FILES superglobal. (don't know if AJAX changes that, but I imagine not)

**EDIT2**

Combining the two... this is the general idea. Make your html + JS look like...

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function()
{
  var form_data = new FormData();

  form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0]);
  var booking = $('#bookingNum').val();
  var partner = $('#partnerCode').val();

  form_data.append("booking ",booking); 
  form_data.append("partner",partner);  

  $.ajax({
    url: 'process/customer.php',
    method:"POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('fail: ' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
  
  return false;//prevent default form submission
});
```

```html
<form id='form'>
  <input type='file' id='fileInput' />
  <label for='bookingNum'>Booking Num: </label>
  <input type='text' id='bookingNum' name='bookingNum' />
  <label for='partnerCode'>Partner Code:</label>
  <input type='text' id='partnerCode' name='partnerCode' />
  <button id='uploadBtn'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and try it with your php code like

```
<?php 
if($_POST['bookingNum']){
    var_dump($_POST['bookingNum']);
}
if($_POST['partnerCode']){
    var_dump($_POST['partnerCode']);
}
if($_FILES['file']){
    var_dump($_FILES['file']);
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I did remove the async from my actual code.  No errors, but nothing is returning to the console.  I will attempt your suggestions.

Comment: @JohnBeasley I updated my answer. I think you have 2 problems at work, and this is just half the equation. If you combine the changes to the PHP side with tanmay dey's suggestions, I think you might get there

Comment: I just cannot get anything to post over to the PHP side.  :(

Comment: @JohnBeasley I made another edit to try and give you the whole picture. It might not be perfect with your exact environment, but hopefully it gives to a clearer idea of the general approach/how things should work. worst comes to worst, just have a `var_dump($_POST)` on the server-side and debug whether the remaining problem is on the JS half or php half from there. (the var_dump will let you know if it's an empty array you're getting on the php side, which is why I prefer it to echo.)

Comment: Well, I am bringing the formData back now.  Thank you, sir.  Although, I am not getting the booking or partner.  It's a start.  I do appreciate your help, along with the help from tanmayDey  .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#uploadBtn').on('click', function()
{
  var form_data = new FormData();

  form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('ID').files[0]);
  var booking = $('#bookingNum').val();
  var partner = $('#partnerCode').val();

  form_data.append("booking ",booking); 
  form_data.append("partner",partner);  

  $.ajax({
    url: 'process/customer.php',
    method:"POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('fail: ' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I attempted your code, but got the following error:  Cannot read property 'files' of null .  Not sure who downvoted you.

Comment: Apologies, there was no error.  But there are no results either.

Comment: @JohnBeasley Looking at it, I think this actually should work I think. make sure you changed `document.getElementID('ID')` to have the Id of your actual file input element.

Comment: What do you think it should look like on the PHP side?

Comment: $booking =$_POST("booking ");
$partner =$_POST("partner ");
$file=$_FILES["file"]["name"];