# PHP - renaming a file before uploading

Tags: php, jquery, function, file-upload, file-rename

I am trying to build off [a question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976917/jquery-unable-to-pass-formdata-with-other-parameters).

I am able to pass the file over to PHP using the ajax method.  But I need to be able to change the file name to the booking number.  For some reason, the booking was not being passed over to the PHP script.  So I attempted the following:

```
$('#uploadBtn').on('click', function()
{
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('pdfFile').files[0]);
  var booking = $('#bookingNum').val();
  var partner = $('#partnerCode').val();

  $.post('process/fileUpload.php', {booking:booking, partner:partner}, function(data)
  {
    // Wasn't sure if I needed anything here
    console.log(data);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: 'process/fileUpload.php',
    method:"POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){console.log(data);},
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log('fail: ' + errorThrown);}     
  });
});
```

As you will notice above, I had to use the $.post method to send the booking and partner over to the php script.

I then used $.ajax to send the form_data over to the same script.

(I could not achieve this in one motion from yesterday's question I asked.  So this is my second attempt to complete this.  If there is a way to send all of the info in one motion, please refer to the question I linked above.)

So over in the PHP script, I am able to get all of the items I needed with a couple of functions:

```
<?php
  // from the $.post method
  if(isset($_POST['booking']))
  {
    $booking = $_POST['booking'];
    $partner = $_POST['partner'];
    getInfo($booking);
  }
  // from the $.ajax method
  if($_FILES['file'])
  {
    $file = var_dump($_FILES['file']);
    getFile($file);
  }

  function getInfo($booking)
  {
    return $booking;
  }

  function getFile($file)
  {
    return $file;
  }
?>
```

I know it's not pretty, but I am able to get the booking (I don't need the partner right now), and I am also able to get the file information.

What I need to do is rename the file to the booking, and then finally upload it to the necessary directory.

I wasn't sure if I had to combine the functions, but I did try to no avail.

With that said, I am able to get the booking and file info within the PHP script.  Now how would I go about renaming the file to the booking?

Comment: Don't do this - fix the issue from the last question. Solve your issue by sending two requests is totally the wrong way!

Comment: @Phillipp - Will do.  I have abandoned it already.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your ajax request (especially the illegal invocation), use the following javascript code

```
$('#uploadBtn').on('click', function()
{
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('pdfFile').files[0]);
    form_data.append('booking', $('#bookingNum').val());
    form_data.append('partner', $('#partnerCode').val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'process/fileUpload.php',
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
    });
});
```

Notice the use of `processData: false` and `contentType: false`

Comment: The problem I'm having is over on the PHP side.  I can echo the file info, but I cannot get the booking.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Philipp Looks like we have a https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Comment: Come on, now.  I don't want anyone to do my work.  Everything I have attempted has failed.  As stated, I can echo the file info on the PHP side, but I cannot seem to echo the booking.  How is that traits of a "help-vampire"?

Comment: @Philipp - I just edited your answer with the revised PHP code I attempted.

Comment: It seems, you don't - just tested it and the example above works perfectly. I `$_POST['booking']` is empty, it was empty at the point you sended the request..

Comment: Why not just doing a unconditioned `var_dump($_POST)`? This way, you would see all received field - even, if they are empty

Comment: I will attempt that, but I am not understanding why the booking is empty, when I can console the booking prior to posting it.

Comment: Ok - your suggestion of using the unconditioned var_dump seems to be helping me.  I appreciate both of your help.  I still don't understand why I was accused of being a "help-vampire", but that's fine.  Thank you again.  I will mark your suggestions as answered.

Comment: @JohnBeasley: a help vampire is someone who asks a lot of questions without trying to do enough of the work themselves. There's an [old article here](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) that may be useful. The difficulty with the definition is that the correct amount of their own work that a person should do will vary from one person to another. If you get a snippet of help, then make a solid effort with that, before asking for another round of help (clarification requests are OK, but if it is too broad, it may sound like a request for free work).

Comment: Your comment about ("Thoughts?") is excessively broad, and _sounds_ like an invitation for someone to do the necessary debugging. I can see why someone thought that this was rather vague in this case. If you can make your questions much more specific, that will help you show you are not looking for free work. Remember that we really do have people like that here, so we have to guard against it.

Comment: Finally, "any chance you can show me how the PHP code should look", from another answer, is a classic vamp reply. That really is an unmistakable do-it-for-me request. Avoid this at all costs!

Answer (score 2):

As you used `form_data.append()` to add the file data to the formdata. did it not occur to you to also use that to add the booking and partner values to it as well?

```
$('#uploadBtn').on('click', function()
{
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('pdfFile').files[0]);
    form_data.append('booking', $('#bookingNum').val());
    form_data.append('partner', $('#partnerCode').val());

    $.post('process/fileUpload.php', form_data, function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

Comment: I cannot use $.post method in this case, as I get an "illegal invocation" error.

Comment: And when I use the $.ajax method, I only get the file info.

Comment: Thats because you need to re-jig your PHP code to work when all the data arrives in one post

Comment: Oh and you should use `echo json_encode($something);` to return data to the AJAX call

Comment: any chance you can show me how the PHP code should look?  I cannot seem to print out the booking or partner?

Comment: It would look like any other form processing code in PHP, millions of examples out there